# O que é o Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou usando o retrofit em um aplicativo para consumir um Web Service Java e estou na dúvida:

> O Retrofit é uma biblioteca ou uma API?

Comment: Imagino que o Retrofit é uma biblioteca que possui uma API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > O que é o Retrofit

O Retrofit é uma biblioteca desenvolvida pela Square que é utilizada como um ***REST Client*** no Android e Java. Utiliza a biblioteca ***OkHttp*** para fazer os ***Http Requests***.

O Retrofit torna mais fácil recuperar e fazer upload de JSON através de uma ***Web service REST***. 
Com o Retrofit tu podes escolher que conversor usar para a serialização de dados, como por exemplo o ***GSON***.

Answer (score 4):

[Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) é uma biblioteca Java para criar type-safe HTTP clients seguros para aplicativos Android

#### Como assim `type-safe`?

A segurança proporcionada pelo retrofit é o fato dele, originalmente, obrigar o desenvolvedor a desenvolver uma `interface`. Se você é novo no mundo do Java e não sabe o que é uma `interface` eu recomendo ler [esse](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/interfaces/) conteúdo.

Mas fazendo um breve resumo, uma `interface` é um tipo de contrato, na qual você para utilizar recursos especificos é necessário implementar os métodos presentes na sua `interface`. O `type-safe` do Retrofit vem devido a isso, pois você deve na sua interface define os requests que o seu client vai utilizar e em que tipo de estrutura de dados ele deve retornar, por exemplo:

```
// Interface para o endpoit de repositórios de um usuário específico
public interface GitHubService {
   @GET("users/{user}/repos")
   Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);

   // Defina aqui outros métodos com os mais variados tipos de retorno
}
```

A implementação ficaria da seguinte maneira.

```
// Configuração do Retrofit
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();
// Objeto que implementa a interface
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

// Como o método "listRepos" da interface "GitHubService" retorna um 
// Call<List<Repo>> vamos criar um objeto equivalete.
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Dessa maneira você consegue deixar bem claro qual o tipo de dado cada endpoit deve trazer. E se seu app utiliza mais de uma serviço, podes criar um package `example.services` na qual todos as suas interfaces estarão presentes. Deixando seu projeto mais organizado.